# How can I use the size of an initialised vector in an external function, in C?

Tags: c, arrays, vector

I am a beginner at using C.
I have program that takes two vectors, finds their difference as a vector and computes its length. I am trying to generalise it so that any vectors of any size can be put in without any other change. I find an issue when trying to input the size of the vector into the external function, **modulus**. It will print off random numbers in the correct format, mostly zero, so the true error is unclear. What am I doing wrong?

```
int i, l;

float modulus(float vec[], int length);
void main() {
  /* declare and initialise a position vector */
  float positionVector1[] = {6.0, 3.0};
  float positionVector2[] = {3.0, 2.0};
  int L = sizeof(positionVector1);
  float positionVector[L];
  for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    positionVector[i] = positionVector2[i] - positionVector1[i];
  }
  float len;
  len = modulus(positionVector, L);
  printf("length is %.2e\n", len);
}

float modulus(float vec[], int length) {
  float mod = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    mod = mod + (vec[i] * vec[i]);
  }
  mod = sqrt(mod);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof X` tells you how many *bytes* are in `X`, not how many elements. (And it works on any object, not just arrays.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)